# c# memory game, need to add message at the end of game

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a memory game using windows form (c#), the game is complete but I am having difficulty adding the last part, which that when all cards are matched a message box need to show to the user e.g. "Well Done! all cards have been matched".

Here is a section of the code where I think the code for `MessageBox.Show` will be inserted:

```
      private void card1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         //if the first slot of pendingImages is available put this card there for comparison
    {
        //turn card over
        card1.Image = Properties.Resources.Image1;
       //if this is the first card to be turned over, save its image 
        if (pendingImage1 == null)
        {
            pendingImage1 = card1;
        }
        //else check if pendingImage 2 is available then store the card here for comparison
        else if(pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 == null)
        {
            pendingImage2 = card1;
        }
        //if both pendingImage slots are filled then compare the cards
        if (pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 != null)
        {
            if (pendingImage1.Tag == pendingImage2.Tag)
            {
                //clear the variables to be used again
                pendingImage1 = null;
                pendingImage2 = null;
                //once the cards are matched and turned permanentaly, disable the card to make it unclickable
                card1.Enabled = false;
                dupCard1.Enabled = false;
                //add 10 points to the score evry time cards match
                scoreSheet.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(scoreSheet.Text) + 10);
            }
            else
            {
                flipDuration.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void dupCard1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dupCard1.Image = Properties.Resources.Image1;
        if (pendingImage1 == null)
        {
            pendingImage1 = dupCard1;
        }
        else if (pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 == null)
        {
            pendingImage2 = dupCard1;
        }
        if (pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 != null)
        {
            if (pendingImage1.Tag == pendingImage2.Tag)
            {
                pendingImage1 = null;
                pendingImage2 = null;
                card1.Enabled = false;
                dupCard1.Enabled = false;
                scoreSheet.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(scoreSheet.Text) + 10);
            }
            else
            {
                flipDuration.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

These 2 are the 1st 2 of total 18 cards, but this is the code which is for all of them only Properties.Resources.Image1 is changed from Image.1 to Image.2, .3, .4 etc.

I'm not sure what code will allow me to have the game display a message box once all 9 (total 18 cards) pair of cards are matched.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why two methods are necessary. I would create only 1 method and add that to all the images click handlers.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but i guess you want to know when all cards have been paired.You could check the scoreSheet each time a move is made. if there are 10 pair of cards, when the score is 100 you know all have been paired...

Comment: `else if(pendingImage1 != null`   <--  `pendingImage1` is always not-null here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the "best" way to handle this, but you can keep track of the total number of cards that have been matched and the number of matches required to win.  Create a global variable called "winCount" and another variable called "currentMatches". winCount can be manually set in the code to be 9 `int winCount = 9` and the game displays the "You Win" pop up when `currentMatches == winCount`.

For example:

```
int winCount = 9;
int currentMatches = 0;

private void card1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     //if the first slot of pendingImages is available put this card there for comparison
{
    //turn card over
    card1.Image = Properties.Resources.Image1;
   //if this is the first card to be turned over, save its image 
    if (pendingImage1 == null)
    {
        pendingImage1 = card1;
    }
    //else check if pendingImage 2 is available then store the card here for comparison
    else if(pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 == null)
    {
        pendingImage2 = card1;
    }
    //if both pendingImage slots are filled then compare the cards
    if (pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 != null)
    {
        if (pendingImage1.Tag == pendingImage2.Tag)
        {
            //clear the variables to be used again
            pendingImage1 = null;
            pendingImage2 = null;
            //once the cards are matched and turned permanentaly, disable the card to make it unclickable
            card1.Enabled = false;
            dupCard1.Enabled = false;
            //add 10 points to the score evry time cards match
            scoreSheet.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(scoreSheet.Text) + 10);

            //NEW CODE
            currentMatches ++;
            if(currentMatches == winCount)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You Win!)
                 return;
            }
        }            
        else
        {
            flipDuration.Start();
        }     
    }
}

private void dupCard1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dupCard1.Image = Properties.Resources.Image1;
    if (pendingImage1 == null)
    {
        pendingImage1 = dupCard1;
    }
    else if (pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 == null)
    {
        pendingImage2 = dupCard1;
    }
    if (pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 != null)
    {
        if (pendingImage1.Tag == pendingImage2.Tag)
        {
            pendingImage1 = null;
            pendingImage2 = null;
            card1.Enabled = false;
            dupCard1.Enabled = false;
            scoreSheet.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(scoreSheet.Text) + 10);
        }
        else
        {
            flipDuration.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked.... i was trying to do it but put it it in all dupCards but nothing was happening, then i just pasted it in all 18 cards and it worked!

Comment: Awesome!  You can probably refactor the code to one entire method, but if you are going to reset all your variables every time you flip a card, you need to store the values you do not want to reset, outside of the methods :)

Comment: @Mr.Ak and don't forget to up vote correct answers! :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to count the matches. Every time the player paired two images a match counter should be increased.

I would put it this code here:

```
if (pendingImage1.Tag == pendingImage2.Tag)
{
    /* your existing code */

    matches++;

    if (matches == 9)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations. You've successfully paired all the images.");
    }
}
```

part.

Maybe this is not a copy-paste code for you, but I hope you get the idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  private void card1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     //if the first slot of pendingImages is available put this card there for comparison
{
    //turn card over
    card1.Image = Properties.Resources.Image1;
   //if this is the first card to be turned over, save its image 
    if (pendingImage1 == null)
    {
        pendingImage1 = card1;
    }
    //else check if pendingImage 2 is available then store the card here for comparison
    else if(pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 == null)
    {
        pendingImage2 = card1;
    }
    //if both pendingImage slots are filled then compare the cards
    if (pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 != null)
    {
        if (pendingImage1.Tag == pendingImage2.Tag)
        {
            //clear the variables to be used again
            pendingImage1 = null;
            pendingImage2 = null;
            //once the cards are matched and turned permanentaly, disable the card to make it unclickable
            card1.Enabled = false;
            dupCard1.Enabled = false;
            //add 10 points to the score evry time cards match
            scoreSheet.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(scoreSheet.Text) + 10);
            int TotalPoints = Convert.ToInt32(scoreSheet.Text);
            if(TotalPoints >= 100){
                    MessageBox.Show("Your message");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            flipDuration.Start();
        }
    }
}

private void dupCard1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dupCard1.Image = Properties.Resources.Image1;
    if (pendingImage1 == null)
    {
        pendingImage1 = dupCard1;
    }
    else if (pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 == null)
    {
        pendingImage2 = dupCard1;
    }
    if (pendingImage1 != null && pendingImage2 != null)
    {
        if (pendingImage1.Tag == pendingImage2.Tag)
        {
            pendingImage1 = null;
            pendingImage2 = null;
            card1.Enabled = false;
            dupCard1.Enabled = false;
            scoreSheet.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(scoreSheet.Text) + 10);
            int TotalPoints = Convert.ToInt32(scoreSheet.Text);
            if(TotalPoints >= 100){
                    MessageBox.Show("Your message");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            flipDuration.Start();
        }
    }
}
```